# Hibernate ProcedureCall with input List of parameters

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a stored procedure that calls like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numbers_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

declare
  vess_ids numbers_tbl := numbers_tbl(91,250,251,48,339,145,172,202,174);
  rez Number(19,0);
begin
  dev4.limits_get_comp_catch(vess_ids, rez);
  dbms_output.put_line(rez);
end;
```

and I'm looking for a way to call it from my java application using hibernate.

```
ProcedureCall call = getCurrentSession().createStoredProcedureCall("limits_get_comp_catch");
```

Kinda stuck on how to pass a `List<Long>` to the procedure. Any ideas?

Comment: You can transform the list to a string separed with ','

Comment: Alright. Also a question. How do i register the OUT parameter that's named `rez` in my pl/sql code? It's of type `NUMBER`.
If i just register it as 
`Long rez = null;
call.registerParameter(1, Long.class,ParameterMode.OUT).bindValue(rez);`

I get a error `Cannot bind value to non-input parameter`